# A rainy day question

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

Can 'happy' in the sentence: "I don't feel too happy about going outside in the rain", be replaced with 'enamoured' to make the sentence: "I don't feel too enamoured about going outside in the rain. Does enamoured work as a suitable substitute for happy in the way that the word 'enthusiastic' does?

Comment: It looks like the speaker is putting to practice their new [word of the day](https://www.google.com/search?ei=zp53XNzaMoXLwQK8gJ3gAQ&q=%22word+of+the+day%22&oq=%22word+of+the+day%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67l4j0l2j0i67l2j0l2.10862.15131..15406...0.0..0.129.671.1j5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i30.q03LJLf9rkE). Keep it simple, keep it natural, keep the "happy"

Comment: To start with, get the meanings and usage examples for the two words. See how they compare and how they differ in meaning and usage. Good Luck.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Also the [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/enamour) suggests that **enamoured** should be followed by **of, with** or **by** and then proceeds to give a long list of examples that use only **of**. I don't belive that "enamoured about" is correct at all. The OP is using the British spelling as well so, even if "enamored about" is an American usage then the OP's sentence is non-standard and the sentence should read "I am not enamoured of (_or with, or by_) going out in the rain.

Comment: We usually say 'enamoured _of_'. It means 'in love with', so using it in a context like this would only be possible as a humorous exaggeration.

Comment: I agree that happiness is a lovely word, and it is interesting that the 'word of the day' link led to [petrichor](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/petrichor).  I still find enthuasism to the matter is more appropriate personally.

Comment: I'm really not too enamoured of this weather...

Answer (score 0):

Happy is fine. “Enamoured about” and “Enamoured of” don’t sound right. (“Enamoured with” feels less awkward to me. I’m from Canada, where we constantly struggle to balance British and American expressions.)

Comment: Fair answer, but "enamoured" is still not a good choice. I think the OP is searching for "enthusiastic" perhaps.

Comment: “Enthusiastic” might seem a bit, well, enthusiastic. If you are looking a phrase that expresses about the same level of annoyance at the rain as “not too happy”, “not too pleased” might be a more natural sounding replacement.